# Nativescript Angular "View not added to this instance" error on conditional component display

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, angular-nativescript

I have been having this issue with my angular native script app for a while now and cannot seem to move forward with any of the fixes suggested online.

The issue is:

```
View not added to this instance. View: ProxyViewContainer(315) CurrentParent: undefined ExpectedParent: ScrollView(198)
```

Let's look at the parent component that holds the components:

full-layout.component.tns.html

```
  <RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton [drawerContentSize]="innerHeight" gesturesEnabled="false"
                 drawerLocation="Left" (drawerClosed)="onDrawerClosed()">
    <page-router-outlet tkMainContent></page-router-outlet>
    <GridLayout tkDrawerContent rows="auto, *" class="sideStackLayout">
     <ScrollView row="1">
       <component-one *ngIf="showComponentOne"></component-one>
       <component-two *ngIf="showComponentTwo" (backEvent)="backToDefaultComponent()"></component-two>
     </ScrollView>
   </GridLayout>
```

Here what is happening is that inside the rad side drawer there are multiple components displayed and hid using true false conditions and output events from the chile components(component-one, component-two) to the parent(full-layout) component. On this particular component-two component, when going back using the same event it displays this error. I have no idea why as other components are working fine with the same layout structure and functionality.

EDIT:
We debugged with each element of the code and narrowed it down to the

```
private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
```

injection in the constructer used for modal creation. If you remove this it works as expected. Is this a bug?

Angular version: 8.2.14
NS version: 6.7.8

P.s I can share my code somewhere we can get in touch personally maybe?

Comment: You can share your code on : https://stackblitz.com/ and set the url on your post

Comment: The native script implementation of the stackblitz ns is not working for some reason.

Comment: Ok, can you host your code on a github or gitlab public repository ?

Comment: Can i connect with you somehow personally?